# What REST RFC does CodeIgniter follow?

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest, specifications

In the CodeIgniter implementation of REST, what is the RFC specification that it uses?  For instance I have found this [Atom Publishing RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5023) which is deemed the "canonical" REST specification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

REST is a concept, not a specification. The RFC you're looking at is for a specific protocol (ATOM) which uses REST; this is not generally applicable to CodeIgniter (unless you're writing an application which implements ATOM).

Comment: I understand that much.  My question is which RFC does the codeigniter implementation use as a reference.  That is did they match the ATOM specification, do someone else's, or just guess.

Comment: Again, **REST is a concept, not a specification**. There is no RFC for "object-oriented programming", and there is no RFC for "representational state transfer" (REST) either, because neither one can be nailed down by a specification.

Comment: that analog helps a great deal.  Thanks much.